# Can;t install lxml package on windwos 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, lxml

```
"PS D:\Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master\12-Advanced Python Modules\puzzle_unzip> pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: lxml
  DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [96 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
      running install
      C:\Users\lohar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\lxml
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -IC:\Users\lohar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\lohar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
      etree.c
      C:\Users\lohar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v8_cypj7\lxml_b1e7951ab83046e384fffcd4610d3736\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
      Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      creating Users
      creating Users\lohar
      creating Users\lohar\AppData
      creating Users\lohar\AppData\Local
      creating Users\lohar\AppData\Local\Temp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /TcC:\Users\lohar\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInituop21067.c /FoUsers\lohar\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInituop21067.obj
      xmlXPathInituop21067.c
      C:\Users\lohar\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInituop21067.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
PS D:\Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master\12-Advanced Python Modules\puzzle_unzip> "
```

- im trying to install lxml library by pip install lxml.
- i also installed vs build tools 2022 .
- after that i stuck on this error i tryed multiple things but they dont work
- thigs that i tried manually installing packages.
- multiple internet solutions

im expecting a solution to install lxml on W11 machine.and also im using vs code and pycharm python version 3.11 and pip version 22.3.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `lxml` module is a language-binding / wrapper for two C libraries.

For Windows they provide binary builds that include these libraries. Otherwise it will be pain and suffering getting it installed and running on Windows. Because it's Windows. "Developers, developers, developers".. (As lxml developers put it: "users of that platform usually fail to build lxml themselves")

Normally you should get the binary distribution when doing install through pip but in this case you don't.

1. Try to pin an older version, maybe binaries are available for it:

   ```
   pip install lxml==4.9.0
   ```
2. Try to download the lxml binary distribution by Christoph Gohlke [available here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

   You can install the wheel file also via pip.

Sources:

1. [Where are the binary builds?](https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#where-are-the-binary-builds)
2. [Source builds on MS Windows](https://lxml.de/installation.html#source-builds-on-ms-windows)

Comment: thanks their i tried older version that doesn't work either

Comment: i dowloaded the bianary file but what to do next can u guide

Comment: thanks very much i install it using wheel file my problem is solve dnow